# Is there modern function call approach which supports both sync and async execution modes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I make a program in javascript with API. Right now this API works on callbacks and it support both synchronous and asynchronous execution models.

API call example:

```
API.getInfo((err, info) => {
    if(err) return processError(err);
    doSomethingUseful(info);
})
```

I have two API executors - local and remote.

Local executor example:

```
state.info = {...};
API.getInfo = (cb) => cb(null, clone(state.info));
```

Remote executor example:

```
API.getInfo = (cb) => doGet('/info').then(info => cb(null, info), cb)
// express transforms this query to local executor and returns answer
```

The trick is that API can call itself like:

```
API.getOtherInfo = (cb) => {
    let part1, part2;
    API.getPart1((err, data) => part1 = data);
    API.getPart2((err, data) => part2 = data);
    cb(null, {part1, part2})
}
```

In this case it is sync and I want it to be sync.

Callbacks can support both sync and async execution modes.

So now I want to use modern javascript but unfortunately promises are asynchronous by definition. Is there modern javascript approach for sync and async execution except callbacks?

Comment: Use async() convert synchronized function to asynchronoized function I think you search for that option

Comment: The usual design for an API endpoint that can sometimes be sync and sometimes async is to make the external API always be asynchronous.  Then, the caller does one asynchronous design that always works (whether the internals are synchronous or not).  Promises work just fine for this because they help you make it always asynchronous.

Comment: @jfriend00 so the only option is making promise wrapper around sync core?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a promise wrapper around sync core.  If you have a synchronous value that you want to return asynchronously then instead of `return value`, use `return Promise.resolve(value)`.